# Subtitle below logo on actionbar android

Tags: android

I'm trying to place a logo that will act as the actionbar title and then have dynamic fragment based subtitles with text below.

Can you either set text below logo or the title as an image?

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ActionBar does not provides APIs for setting title as an image, you could try find the actual TextView in layout but I would not recommend that due Android fragmentation. It will not work on all devices.

You can however use a [custom view in ActionBar](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html#menu_customviews), you will have to call

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```